# Trying to determine screen views by region

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery and have limited experience with SQL, but have been making a few queries successfully.

One complicated one which I am a bit stuck on is breaking down the number of screen views by a user's region.

My SQL query looks like this

```
SELECT 
  geo.region, COUNT(params.value.string_value) as count
FROM 
  `xxx`, 
  UNNEST(event_params) as params
WHERE
  geo.country = "Australia" AND geo.region > "" AND event_name = "screen_view" AND params.key = "firebase_screen"
GROUP BY 
  geo.region
ORDER BY
  count DESC
```

I get some output which is quite a significant amount less than what the Firebase console reports for total screen views in Australia.

```
Row   region              count 
1     Victoria            25613
2     South Australia     3557
...
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: There may not be anything wrong with the above query at all, insofar that it is doing what you wrote.  Can you also include the SQL behind what you see in the Firebase console?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you mean the SQL query that Firebase uses? Is that possible to find somewhere?

Comment: @Ricky what happens if you remove any of this conditions from the `WHERE` part `AND geo.region > "" AND event_name = "screen_view" AND params.key = "firebase_screen"`. I mean try to compare bare data with Firebase to see all your data was imported and than focus on the query

Comment: @TamirKlein The numbers skyrocket to much bigger numbers. I think this is because the events in BigQuery are much more granular than the ones that Firebase reports on, that's why I have these conditions set.

Comment: Hi @Ricky If you can't see the numbers are aligned maybe you will need to contact Firebase team as your sql looks OK. I believe first try to check if all data was imported and than focus on the sql which is what you are actually doing. Maybe OP can provide more help on this.

Comment: Thanks @TamirKlein I've reached out to Firebase to ask about these differences.